# Are my Magento permissions correct?

Tags: php, magento, file-permissions, mamp, error-reporting

I have a fresh install of Magento 1.4.1.1 using MAMP 1.8.4 on OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.4.

I'm unable to load magento/downloader (the Magento Connect Manager) successfully. My browser displays a blank white page. Safari's Activity window tells me it's an Internal Server Error, which tells me my permissions may be incorrect. I have changed all file permissions for the entire magento directory to 777 to test whether the directories/files had sufficient privileges. I'm still unable to load Magento connect (magento/downloader/).

Would setting all files to 777 be a sufficient way to test correct permissions? Anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the include_path in my php.ini file was wrong. The path should be:

.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php

I had previously installed the Zend Framework and forgot about it. Part of the setup process of ZF, I believe, is to change or modify your include_path. If I would have erased and re-installed MAMP, it would have solved the problem as well.

Thanks, Jonathan, for your input.

Comment: No problem, it often seems to be one of those annoying little config values!  If my answer was helpful, feel free to upvote or accept it.  Cheers, JD

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your MAMP server meets [the requirements](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento/), have you turned on PHP [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) and scanned the logs for errors?  Turned on Magento's [logging and developer mode](http://alanstorm.com/magento_log_and_developer_mode)?  Try posting the results of those so we can help you.

Comment: I've begun the process from the beginning. I have downloaded Magento 1.4.1.1 and uncompressed it. When I run magento-check.php inside Magento directory, it tells me that my server does not meet the following requirements: You need MySQL 4.1.2 or greater. Logging into MySQL (/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -uroot -p), I'm told that the server version is 5.1.37. Placing a phpinfo.php file in the Magento directory reads the same. It also tells me the PHP version is 5.2.11

Comment: I've turned on PHP error_reporting by uncommenting the E_ALL line (240) in the php.ini file located at /Users/shortname/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5/

Regardless of the magento-check.php requirement for MySQL not being supposedly met, I can successfully install Magento. I logged into the backend, and before doing anything else, I click on System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings and set Enabled to Yes. Save Config. Then I created a /var/log directory with permissions set to 755.

Comment: Then, in the backend, I click on System > Magento Connect > Magento Connect Manager and immediately get a blank screen. The URL reads: http://localhost:8888/xxx/xxx/magento/downloader/?return=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fxxx%2Fxxx%2Fmagento%2Findex.php%2Fadmin%2F

/Users/shortname/Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log and find about 600 lines of errors that look like this:

http://pastie.org/1260189

magento/var/log/system.log shows the following: 

http://pastie.org/1260191

Looks like permission issues. But, I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this information.